# In MeteorJS helpers being called before subscriptionsReady and give exceptions from the console. Why?

Tags: meteor

I put my subscription inside:

```
Template.home.onCreated(function (){
  this.subscribe( 'preferences', function() {
    $( ".loader" ).delay( 1000 ).fadeOut( 'slow', function() {
    $( ".loading-wrapper" ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
});

  });
```

I warp helpers call inside:

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}} {{/if}}
```

one of my helpers that causing the exception:

```
Template.preferences.helpers({
payWeekly: function () {
  return findPreferences().payWeekly;
},
```

This is the function used in the helper:

```
export const findPreferences = function()  {
      var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()});
      var preferences = preferencesCollection.find({companyId:currentUser.companyId});
      var preferencesInstance = preferences.fetch()[0];
      return preferencesInstance;
```

but I still get exceptions in the console that helpers being called before the subscriptionsReady is ready.

One of the exceptions that I get:

```
Exception in template helper: showConfirmationPanel@http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=753c258a548b86565f5083306a240b5c9d728c22:12007:12
bindDataContext/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3051:14
Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1715:14
wrapHelper/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3103:14
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744:12
wrapHelper/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3102:12
Spacebars.call@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a:172:12
template.home.js/Template.home</</<@http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=753c258a548b86565f5083306a240b5c9d728c22:8771:14
Blaze.If/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2734:44
viewAutorun/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1934:18
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744:12
viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1932:14
Blaze._withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271:12
viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1931:12
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:339:5
Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:229:5
Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:613:11
Blaze.View.prototype.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1944:14
Blaze.If/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2733:5
fireCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2014:19
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:640:12
Blaze._fireCallbacks/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2011:5
Blaze._withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271:12
Blaze._fireCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2010:3
Blaze._createView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2028:3
Blaze._materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2073:3
materializeDOMInner@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1532:9
Blaze._materializeDOM@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1474:3
Blaze._materializeDOM@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1483:7
doMaterialize@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2092:32
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:640:12
doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2090:9
viewAutorun/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1934:18
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744:12
viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1932:14
Blaze._withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271:12
viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1931:12
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:339:5
Tracker.Computation.prototype._recompute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:358:9
Tracker._runFlush@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:532:9
onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=6d285d84547b3dad9717a7c89c664b61b45ea3d8:398:23
```

Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: There’s info missing. Can you post your helper code?

Comment: @RicardoPesciotta Done, added to question details

Comment: @MJO Can you please post the type exception/error you're getting in the console? But I speculate that the returned value in your helper relies on yet-to-be fetched data.

Comment: @HarryAdel I added the exception to the details. Could you explain more please?

Comment: Well, is `preferencesCollection` available in your template? Also, does placing the code inside of `findPreferences` directly in your helper help?

Comment: @HarryAdel no it does not help. I just tried it.

Comment: Have you tried logging this line `var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()});` There might be no meteor user. It'd be nice if you can give us a repository containing most of the code to this issues, so that we can debug it fully without going back and forth.

Comment: @HarryAdel no, but the strange thing is that all helpers that cause the exceptions  works just fine as expected

Comment: I don't know dude, kinda at a loss here. O.o!

Comment: @HarryAdel thanks anyway